# Building Qt4.8.x on OS X 10.7 with xcode 4.6 or higher

Tags: qt, build, webkit, osx-lion, osx-snow-leopard

Can I build Qt 4.8.x on OSX 10.7.x using XCode 4.6.x and deploy the application on osx 10.6.x 10.7.x 10.8.x i.e. on Snow Leopard, Lion and Mountain Lion?

I am trying since several days but no result I even tried to explicitly specify -sdk ..10.6.sdk after giving aias Developer/Sdk/... But having very tough time.

Webkit complains it cannot find symbol " _kCFWebServicesProviderDefaultDisplayNameKey" that is referenced from QtWebKit.

I see on Qt's bug site that few people says they were able to do it by using sdk 10.6.sdk using lower xcode, but I dont understand why I do need to use 10.6 ?

Technically the SDK shouldn't matter, as long as "-mmacosx-version-min=10.6" is set as deployment target.